# Add padding to a custom contentComponent for a DrawerNavigator to avoid overlaying the status bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-drawer

When using a basic DrawerNavigator, there is proper paddingTop that avoids overlaying content over the status bar; however, when adding a custom contentComponent, the padding is not there. Code: https://github.com/myplaceonline/testreactexpo/tree/drawermargin

Without custom contentComponent on Android:

[image: Without custom contentComponent]

With custom contentComponent on Android:

[image: With custom contentComponent]

I can add some explicit margin, but what value should I choose? I'm already using `SafeAreaView`, but I believe that's only for iOS.

Here's the code. Comment the `contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,` line to see the working view.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';

class TestScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Test",
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

export default AppDrawer = createAppContainer(
  createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      DrawerTest: {
        screen: createStackNavigator(
          {
            Test: TestScreen
          },
        ),
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: "Test",
        }
      },
    },
    {
      contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    }
  )
);
```

```html
<div data-snack-id="@git/github.com/myplaceonline/testreactexpo@drawermargin" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

<ScrollView style={{paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
```

Comment: How do you get that 'Constants'?